# Trying to connect to gateway in static ip network

Tags: networking, arch-linux, ip, routing, raspberry-pi

I have arch-linux-arm running on a raspberryPi.
The network I am in uses static IPs.
`gateway IP` is `192.168.178.5`
IP for my device is `192.168.178.201`

To connect to the internet I use:
`ip addr add 192.168.178.201 dev eth0`
`ip route add default via 192.168.178.5`
However the latter yields
`RTNETLINK answeres: Network is unreachable`
What am I missing?

**UPDATE**
[mtak's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/140701/61486) fixed the initial problem,
however I still cannot reach the gateway.
Attempting to `ping` result in `destination host unreachable`

Comment: Is the link up? `ip link set eth0 up`

Comment: @Patrick yup. Initial problem already solved by mtak's answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add a subnet mask when you add the IP address. Now the system will think the IP is a /32, which does not include the ip 192.168.178.5, therefore it's unreachable.

To add the new IP address with a subnet mask:

```
ip addr add 192.168.178.201/24 dev eth0
```

Comment: Now it does not complain anymore when trying to set the route. However I still don't get to the internet. `ping` on the gateway itself results in `destination host unreachable`

Comment: same problem here.. did you manage to get it to work?

Comment: I also cannot get this to work, and am at the same point as Mark and branquito

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me

```
ip route flush dev eth0
ip route add 10.77.132.0/24 dev eth0
ip route add 0.0.0.0/0 via 10.77.132.1
```

Comment: Be careful with the `flush` command on default interface. If you have reached the server via that interface, you will loose connection to it.

Answer (score 2):

Do you not have systemd and netctl? that's what arch usually uses. If you are not bound to using ip to connect to the internet, you can paste this into **/etc/netctl/ethernet**

```
Interface=eth0
Connection=ethernet
IP=static
Address=('192.168.178.201/24' '192.168.1.87/24')
#Routes=('192.168.0.0/24 via 192.168.1.2')
Gateway='192.168.178.5'
DNS=('192.168.178.5')
```

then execute **netctl start ethernet** (and if that works, **netctl enable ethernet** to auto-connect on bootup) this is the recommended way to connect to the internet on arch as far as I can understand.

Based on your former problems, I would guess that the issue might be that you are forgetting to define a DNS server (although it might be automated, I don't know)

If you still fail to reach the gateway, maybe you should double check your gateway's IP. Have you tried connecting with DHCP (like **dhcpcd**? or does your network simply not support that at all?) just to make sure that the connection can be made at all?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
ip route add 192.168.178.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.122.201
```

I flush my route main table, set static ip, encounter this problem.

I try to delete the static ip, readd again, observe what has been added to route table, and find this entry. Then I add default route, it works.

```
ip a del 192.168.178.201/24 dev eth0
ip a add 192.168.178.201/24 dev eth0
ip route add default via 192.168.178.5 dev eth0
```